# building R packages--Error : example requires a value

Tags: r, package, devtools, roxygen2, roxygen

When I build my package I receive this error. Can you help me know what are the steps to avoid this error?

```
#' Square a number
#' 
#' Takes in any numeric value and squares it
#' @param x A value to be squared
#' @return The square of the input
#' @export
#' @example 
square <- function(x)
{
  return(x^2)
}
```

Here's the error when I press build:

```
==> roxygenize('.', roclets=c('rd', 'collate', 'namespace'))

* checking for changes ... ERROR

Error : example requires a value
```

Comment: You haven't provided any examples in the `@examples` section. Try adding e.g. `#' square(2)` below that line. Alternatively, remove the `@examples` keyword completely.

Comment: I think I am supposed to have that line for the assignment I am given. I was learning roxygen2 on my own with a simpler function but I am stuck. I am supposed to say write example(square) and get a result.

Comment: Apply the first suggestion then.

Comment: @gagolews on a side note, I did what you told and received an error `==> roxygenize('.', roclets=c('rd', 'collate', 'namespace'))

* checking for changes ... ERROR

Error in file(con, "r") : Roclet processing error in block power.r:9
cannot open the connection` for `#' @example 
#' square(2)
square <- function(x)`

Comment: And what about `@examples`?

Comment: Well, it worked. That was really such a subtle observation. Thanks!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51803/discussion-between-mona-jalal-and-gagolews)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

```
#' @title
#' Square a number
#' 
#' @description
#' Takes in any numeric value and squares it
#'
#' @param x A value to be squared
#' @return The square of the input
#'
#' @export
#' @examples
#' square(2) # 2 squared
square <- function(x)
{
  return(x^2)
}
```

Also, make sure you play with the latest `roxygen2` package.